# Python - Add prefix to column dependant on multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm still a bit new to python and would appreciate any help you can offer. 
I have a dataframe (below), for which I want to create a new column which adds a prefix dependant on if there is something in the Identifier 1/2 columns, and if there is nothing in those columns then it adds a different prefix.

```
Company number  Identifier 1    Identifier 2
        123456            11    
        987656                         47861
        123987
        876324         78172
```

The following df is what I want it to eventually look like:

```
Company number  Identifier 1    Identifier 2       New Column
        123456            11                   prefix1-123456
        987656                         47861   prefix2-987656
        123987                                 prefix3-123987
        876324         78172                    prefix1-78172
```

The code below is what I thought could work but I'm getting a few errors:

```
def addPrefix(cell):
  if pd.null(df['Identifier 1']) = False:
    df['new col'] = "prefix1" + df['Company number']
  elif pd.null(df['Identifier 2']) = False:
    df['new col'] = "prefix2" + df['Company number']
  else:
    df['new col'] = "prefix3" + df['identifier']
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Wool At the least, the code above would give a "The truth value of a series is undefined..." error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where` for this:

```
df['NewColumn'] = np.where(df['Identifier1'].notnull(), 'prefix1-',
                           np.where(df['Identifier2'].notnull(), 'prefix2-',
                                    'prefix3-')) + df['CompanyNumber'].astype(str)
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

   CompanyNumber  Identifier1  Identifier2       NewColumn
0         123456         11.0          NaN  prefix1-123456
1         987656          NaN      47861.0  prefix2-987656
2         123987          NaN          NaN  prefix3-123987
3         876324      78172.0          NaN  prefix1-876324
```

Comment: @Phobos, Excellent. Feel free to accept (green tick on left) if this helped.